# Hover functionality matplotlib graph in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, graph, annotations

I am having some trouble displaying annotations on a graph embedded in a tkinter window.

When displayed within the matplotlib window the hover function works fine, however once it is embedded it seems to lose that functionality.

To see how the graph is supposed to respond, uncomment the '#plt.show' command near the bottom.

Looking for some help on how to display the annotations in the tkinter window.
Thanks

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler


def update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata):
    x, y = line.get_data()
    annot.xy = (x[ind["ind"][0]], y[ind["ind"][0]])
    # Get x and y values, then format them to be displayed
    x_values = " ".join(list(map(str, ind["ind"])))
    y_values = " ".join(str(ydata[n]) for n in ind["ind"])
    # Format of label can be changed here
    text = "{}, {}".format(x_values, y_values)
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)


def hover(event, line, annot, ydata):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        # Draw annotations if cursor in right position
        cont, ind = line.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind, line, annot, ydata)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            # Don't draw annotations
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()


def plot_line(x, y):
    line, = plt.plot(x, y, marker="o")
    # Annotation style may be changed here
    annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                        bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
    annot.set_visible(False)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",
                           lambda event: hover(event, line, annot, y))


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas)


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")
x1 = range(21)
y1 = range(0, 21)
# Plot line graphs
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_line(x1, y1)
# plt.show()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate


button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
# If you put root.destroy() here, it will cause an error if the window is
# closed with the window manager.
```